# Spatial operators in R?

Tags: vector, analysis, r, point-in-polygon

How can I do spatial selections or filters in R? I can do this in PostGIS using (e.g.):

```
SELECT * FROM mypoint, mypoly
WHERE ST_Within(mypoint.geom, mypoly.geom);
```

and it is similarly a piece of cake in most other GIS software. So I'd expect something in R to look like:

```
mypoint[within(mypoint, mypoly),]
```

but I can't find any leads anywhere. I'm looking for something that uses the common spatial predicate terminology used in PostGIS/GEOS/JTS/Shapely (within, contains, intersects, overlaps, touches, etc.; DWithin would be bonus). Does this functionality or library exist for R? If not, is there something that is similar?

Note: In R, I use the `sp` class for my objects (`SpatialPointsDataFrame`, etc).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For your specific question, you should be able to use `point.in.polygon` ([docs](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/R_man-2.9.0/library/sp/man/point.in.polygon.html)) or `overlay` ([vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/vignettes/over.pdf)) to perform the analysis.

A spatial predicate language isn't trivial to implement, and all the examples you mentioned boil down to ports or wrappers of JTS at some point. There is a pre-alpha release of [rgeos](http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/rgeos-interface-to-R-classes-sp-others-td4490794.html), a recent Google SOC entry which provides access to GEOS directly from R.

In general, it seems that the R developers are grappling with whether they want to maintain a full GIS implementation within R itself, or instead rely on facilitating packages that allow interaction with PostGIS, GRASS (`spgrass`), SAGA (`rsaga`) and the like to provide deeper spatial savvy.

Comment: `point.in.polygon` is a good start for basic polygons, although a bit crude (e.g.):  `point.in.polygon(pnt@coords[,1], pnt@coords[,2], lake@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords[,1], lake@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords[,2])`

I'm really looking forward to `rgeos` that you mentioned, and has all the [binary predicates](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/R/rgeos_predicate_binary.R?view=markup&root=rgeos) and more.

Comment: For spgrass6 examples with GRASS, see http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/R_statistics

Comment: `rgeos` is now on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgeos/), and is very simple to install/use/etc.